# Django error: Value too long for type character varying(2)

Tags: django, postgresql

I did a database flush to reset my database. I am getting this error when I try to do the following code.

Code that throws error:

```
    try:
        print("Attempting to load %s" % store.get('name'))
        # THIS NEXT LINE THROWS ERROR
        store_obj = Store.objects.get(name=store.get('name'))
    except Store.DoesNotExist:
        store_obj = Store(name=store.get('name'),
                          last_updated=last_updated,
                          address=store.get('address'),
                          city=store.get('city'),
                          state=store.get('state'),
                          zip_code=store.get('zip_code'))
```

Error:

```
Exception Type: DataError at /stores/
Exception Value: value too long for type character varying(2)
```

`\d` of `stores_store`

[image]

Model in django:

```
class Store(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    # Address
    address = models.CharField(_("address"), max_length=128)
    city = models.CharField(_("city"), max_length=128)
    state = USStateField(_("state"))
    zip_code = USZipCodeField(_("zip code"), max_length=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

As you can see the store name is a VARCHAR of 200, not 2. However, I cannot complete this get operation without getting this error. I tried another flush and `makemigrations` -> `migrate` but still have no luck. What else can I try?

Thanks!

Comment: The error field may be state field of the table

Comment: Add the full traceback to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the column "state" has USStateField(_("state")) which I assume is varying(2), are you trying to add a tuple which state is bigger than varying(2)?

I can suggest you to change the USStateField(_("state")) to a CharField or to put a max_length.

If that doesn't work you can try to delete the migrations history to make them again. Inside the app folder in migrations delete all the files that look like 0001_initial.py, don't delete the **init**.py inside the migrations folder, hope it helps :D

Comment: I deleted init.py accidentally, is there a way I can restore that?

Comment: If you didn't wrote manually anything on init.py, just create a new file named init.py. Naturally they don't have anything but it is good to have them.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your migrations file and track the value stated in the error within those files and increase the value to match it with the one in your models.py file and your database