# Exception Value: Value too long for type character varying(2)

Tags: python, django, reactjs, forms

So I am using React and Django. I currently have a problem with submitting forms because I am gettin the strange error `Exception Value: Value too long for type character varying(2)`

EDIT: The error still occurs when the `USStateField` is blank and when a correct 2-letter abbreviation is entered.

Models.py for the Model in question:

```py
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Member(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('last_name', 'first_name')

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    dob = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date of Birth', null=True, blank=True,
                    help_text='format: 1999-12-31')
    card_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, help_text="The ID number on the membership card", unique=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    latest_membership = models.ForeignKey('Membership', null=True, blank=True, related_name='latest_member')
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
    street_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    street_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    state = USStateField(choices=us_states, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True)
```

`us_states` are imported: `from localflavor.us import us_states`

I see there is some fields with `max_length` but I know I am not violating the constraint.

API for React form:

```py
def redesign_member_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        errors = {}
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            data["dob"] = parse(data["dob"])
            print("dob parsed")
            Member.objects.create(**data)
        except Exception as e:
            errors["error"] = e.message
            return JsonResponse(errors, status=400)
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

The react form:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Form from '../../components/form/Form';
import { FormContext } from '../../components/form/Form';
import FormDropdown from '../../components/form/FormDropdown';
import FormDatePicker from '../../components/form/FormDatePicker';
import FormInput from '../../components/form/FormInput';
import FormButton from '../../components/form/FormButton';

import styles from "./Memberships.module.css"
import { setBanner } from '../../util/utils';
import { genericValidator, emailValidator } from '../../util/formValidation';

export default function MemberForm(props) {
  setBanner("Member Form", "/helm/members/member/add/");

  return (
    <div className={`${styles.container}`}>
      <h1 className={`${styles.title}`}>New Member</h1>
      <Form action="/memberships/api/make_member/">
      <FormContext.Consumer>
        { ({ failMessage, successMessage }) => {
          return (
            failMessage ? <div className={`${styles.error} ${styles.message}`}> { failMessage }</div> : null
          );
        }}
      </FormContext.Consumer>
      <div className={`${styles.left}`}>
        <div className={`${styles.input}`}>
            <FormInput
              name="first_name"
              label="First Name"
              validator={genericValidator({required: true})}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={`${styles.input}`}>
            <FormInput
              name="last_name"
              label="Last Name"
              validator={genericValidator({required: true})}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={`${styles.input}`}>
            <FormInput
              name="phone"
              label="Phone Number"
              validator={genericValidator({required: false, type: "number"})}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={`${styles.input}`}>
            <FormDatePicker
              name="dob"
              label="Date of Birth"
              peekNextMonth={true}
              showMonthFormDropdown={true}
              showYearFormDropdown={true}
              FormDropdownMode={"select"}
              validator={genericValidator({required: false})}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={`${styles.input}`}>
            <FormInput
              name="email"
              label="Email"
              validator={emailValidator({required: false})}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={`${styles.input}`}>
            <FormInput
              name="card_number"
              label="Card"
              validator={genericValidator({required: true, type: "number"})}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={`${styles.right}`}>
          <div className={`${styles.input}`}>
            <h1 className={`${styles.subtitle}`}>Address</h1>
          </div>
          <div className={`${styles.input}`}>
            <FormInput
              name="street_1"
              label="Street 1"
              validator={genericValidator({required: false})}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={`${styles.input}`}>
            <FormInput
              name="street_2"
              label="Street 2"
              validator={genericValidator({required: false})}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={`${styles.input}`}>
            <FormInput
              name="city"
              label="City"
              validator={genericValidator({required: false})}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={`${styles.input}`}>
            <FormDropdown
              name="state"
              label="State"
              validator={genericValidator({required: false})}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={`${styles.input}`}>
            <FormInput
              name="zip_code"
              label="Zip Code"
              validator={genericValidator({required: false, type: "number"})}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <FormButton className={`${styles.submit_button}`} text="Submit" />
      </Form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Let me know if there is any other code that would be helpful!

Comment: Check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53113178/django-error-value-too-long-for-type-character-varying2

Answer (score 0):

The `USStateField` is modeled as `CharField` with `max_length=2`.

My guess is that you are trying to save the whole states name instead of its 2-letter abbreviation ([as listed here](https://github.com/django/django-localflavor/blob/master/localflavor/us/us_states.py)).

Comment: The error shows up when the field is blank (it can be null/blank) and when I try to enter the 2-letter abbreviation.

Comment: You defined a us_states in models.py. can you share ?

Comment: @EricMartin `us_states` is imported like so: `from localflavor.us import us_states`

Comment: can you test : from localflavor.us.us_states import US_STATES and use US_STATES in your model choices ?

Answer (score 0):

Your import is wrong :

`from localflavor.us.us_states import US_STATES` and use US_STATES in your model

instead of  `from localflavor.us import us_states`